# What is VBV (Video Buffering Verifier) in H.264?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, video-processing, video-encoding

I can't understand what is a VBV (Video Buffering Verifier) and what relations it have with a maxrate.
When I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -crf 21 -maxrate 750k -bufsize 750k -codec:v:0 libx264 -s 640x360 -r 30 output.mp4
```

output.mp4 video have a bit rate about 730 kb/s
But when I use this command (same command but with -bufsize 5000k):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -crf 21 -maxrate 750k -bufsize 5000k -codec:v:0 libx264 -s 640x360 -r 30 output.mp4
```

output.mp4 video have more bit rate than 750kb/s (about 800-900 kb/s).
Why it happens? Why we need the the bufsize? What does the bufsize do?

Comment: http://video.stackexchange.com/ might also help for future questions like this

Comment: Thank you for helping, aergistal!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Basically the VBV enables you to make sure the encoded stream doesn't overflow or underflow the decoder's buffer. If too much data comes in fast the buffer will overflow and you'll be forced to drop some of it. If data is coming in too slow the buffer will run out and the playback will stall.

It's a bit counter-intuitive but a **VBV underflow** signals an encoder rate buffer *overflow* (video bitrate larger than the input rate) while a **VBV overflow** signals an encoder rate buffer *underflow* (video bitrate lower than input the rate).

For `ffmpeg` the `bufsize` is the size of the buffer. `minrate` and `maxrate` are used in conjunction with `bufsize` to set the max and min bitrate change tolerance for VBR (variable bitrate).

`minrate` is typically used along with `maxrate` to achieve near-CBR (constant bitrate).

`maxrate` is not the peak bitrate, it's rather the maximum bitrate that can enter the buffer. If you have a large buffer, like in your second example, you can tolerate a higher bitrate for a greater amount of time until the buffer overflows. VBV makes sure your bitrate is lowered before that happens. That's why your stream can reach 800-900 kbps.

You can read more here: [The relationship between --vbv-bufsize and --vbv-maxrate](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=147460)

Comment: We use VBV as a hypothetical decoder with a constant input bitrate, but if encoder ouput bitrate decreases, how could decoder receive constant bitrate video and lead to buffer overflow?

Comment: @vacing Based on my understanding the decoder will instantly remove data from the buffer to decode frames with a certain timing for display. Frame sizes are not constant even if the stream bitrate is (for CBR). If the frame data to be removed has a only a small size each time and the buffer keeps filling up at the same constant rate then it would eventually overflow. Larger frame sizes means a larger chunk of the buffer is used at once. Hence the need for padding which is simply discarded in the first case.